# Clipboard API implementation not working on <ul>

Tags: javascript, clipboard

Trying to figure out with the clipboard API is not functioning here:

```js
document.querySelector('#copy').addEventListener('click', e => {
const html = document.querySelector('ul').outerHTML;
  const blob = new Blob([html], {type: 'text/html'});
  const item = new ClipboardItem({['text/html']: blob});
  navigator.clipboard.write([item]).then(() => {
    e.target.innerText = 'Copied!';
  }, () => {
    e.target.innerText = 'Error?';
  });
});
```

```html
<button id="copy">Copy</button>
<ul>
  <li>Hello World!</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, the intention of this was to take a series of <ul>s and copy/paste them into a spreadsheet software, by placing a "Copy" button before each  in the document. I achieved a workaround by doing the following:

```js
(() => {
    document.querySelectorAll('.copy').forEach(button => {
        button.addEventListener('click', () => {
            const text = Array.from(button.nextElementSibling.children).map(e => e.innerText).join("\n");
            const blob = new Blob([text], {type: 'text/plain'});
            const item = new ClipboardItem({['text/plain']: blob});
            navigator.clipboard.write([item]).then(() => {
                button.innerText = 'Copied!';
            }, () => {
                button.innerText = 'ERROR!';
            })
        });
    })
})();
```

```html
<button class="copy">Copy</button>
<ul>
  <li>An item</li>
  <li>Another item</li>
</ul>
```